# Generating random date every month

Tags: java

I have a program running in simulation software that requires generating random date every month.

For e.g: In first time step, let's say first random date is generated for January: 22nd January. It should pick next random date starting from 1st Feb in second time step.

I used following Java code:

```
String strDate = dateFormat.format(date());
OrderDate = LocalDate.parse(strDate)
                     .plus(Period.ofDays((1 + new Random().nextInt(30))));
```

The problem is how do I ensure that it picks next date definitely in next month in my second time step. At the moment, it can pick a random date as 5th January and second date as 22nd January. I want to make sure it picks just one date in a single month

Comment: Every month for how long?  A year?  Two years?  How do we know when it ends?

Comment: There is no specified end date. It can run over a year or up to five years depending on a particular experiment.

Answer (score 3):

Use [`plusMonths`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#plusMonths-long-) to go into the next month, then use [`withDayOfMonth`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#withDayOfMonth-int-) to set a random day between `1` and [`lengthOfMonth`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#lengthOfMonth--):

```
LocalDate date = ...;                                    // get from wherever
date = date.plusMonths(1);                               // go 1 month into the future
int maxDay = date.lengthOfMonth();                       // get max possible day
int randomDayOfMonth = new Random().nextInt(maxDay) + 1; // get random day of month
date = date.withDayOfMonth(randomDayOfMonth);            // set random day of month
```

Answer (score 3):

To generate a random date for a particular month, you need to know the number of days in the month. Use the [`YearMonth`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/YearMonth.html) class to work with months.

E.g. to generate random dates for each month of 2019:

```
Random random = new Random();
for (int month = 1; month <= 12; month++) {
    YearMonth yearMonth = YearMonth.of(2019, month);
    int daysInMonth = yearMonth.lengthOfMonth();
    int dayOfMonth = random.nextInt(daysInMonth) + 1;
    LocalDate localDate = yearMonth.atDay(dayOfMonth);
    System.out.println(localDate);
}
```

*Sample Output*

```
2019-01-12
2019-02-24
2019-03-07
2019-04-28
2019-05-28
2019-06-07
2019-07-20
2019-08-03
2019-09-20
2019-10-31
2019-11-12
2019-12-09
```

If you have a give start date as a string, and want random date in the following month, you can do it like this:

```
Random random = new Random();
String strDate = "2019-01-22";

YearMonth nextMonth = YearMonth.from(LocalDate.parse(strDate)).plusMonths(1);
LocalDate orderDate = nextMonth.atDay(random.nextInt(nextMonth.lengthOfMonth()) + 1);

System.out.println(orderDate);
```

*Sample Output*

```
2019-02-13
```